# iOS9 UIWebView window (frame) height change behavior over iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2

I notice that the iOS 9 WebView does not behave the same as per iOS 8.

That is, the content overflows the window despite a scrollview.

```
lazy var webView = UIWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.frame = view.frame
    webView.delegate = self

    // *** added over the original code in iOS 8, but does not solve anything.
    webView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    webView.scrollView.frame.size = view.frame.size
    webView.scrollView.contentSize = view.frame.size

    // Init with HTML5 app (existing working code in iOS 8)
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    view.backgroundColor =  UIColor.clearColor()
    webView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL:basePath!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

}

Any idea that would help solve the issue?

UPDATE : I added a screen shot (where I forced a height of 512)
[image]

Comment: Can you post the URL you are loading?

Comment: And maybe a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Thanks @joern unfortunately, it's a huge angularJS app that perfectly runs on iOS 8 and fail to "stay" in the screen frame on iOS9. I'm still investigating. It's hard to strip down the app.

Comment: Ah, okay. Maybe I can reproduce it anyway.

Comment: @joern Btw, I am trying to switch to WKWebView in order to see if it suffer the same symptom. Alas, file:// angularjs files don't load and I tried to use 
- loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL: with no more success… bad mood :-/

Comment: Yeah, mondays... By the way I cannot reproduce your issue. I added a UIWebView that is smaller than the device screen but it is not overlapping. It's working as expected and crops its content.

Comment: @joern I found out that the underlying UIWebBrowserView has the wrong height (it shows 1024 where I set 512 for the UIWebView)

Comment: @joern I added a screenshot with the view tree. Do you think one are allowed to directly change the height of the UIWebBrowserView?

Comment: No, it seems that you cannot set the height on UIWebBrowserView (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22110).

Comment: Any update on this? Suffering from same problem, where scrollView content size gets resized automatically with the wrong height.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I managed to find why the height was not handled the same way than in iOS8.

Actually, iOS 8 "fixed" an issue on y side that iOS9 don't (which, on a way, is a better approach).

My index page was wrong in setting the following webkit meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

As you can see, the height was wrongly written device-width. As I said, iOS8 was tolerant and "replaced" to the device-height, I guess. iOS 9 doesn't.

I simply fixed to the meta as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

device-height replaced device-width in the height parameter.

Hope it helps.